# How to get the property of a model in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to get the property of a model in javascript.  So my ajax call is receiving a list of models from the controller.  In javascript, after success, I want to obtain a particular property of the model. Below is my script:

```
$("#filter").keyup(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        url: 'Search',
        success:
        function (result) {
            console.log(result.Books);
            var filter = $("#filter").val();
            console.log(filter);
            // Loop through each row of the table
            result.Books.forEach(
                (function (book, index) {
                    console.log(index);
                    var i = index;
                    var title = book[index];
                    // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
                    if ($(title).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
                        $(book).fadeOut();

                        // Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
                    } else {
                        $(book).show();
                    }
                })
            )
        }

    });
});
```

As you can see, I have tried var title=book[index].  I want something like this:

```
var title = book[index].Title;
```

where Title is one property of the model(here book).  Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Why are you using `book[index]`? `book` will be the item from the list

Comment: you have some extra () in forEach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `book.Title`.

`book` is an element of the `result.Books` collection, so you don't need to use `index`.

Comment: Ok.  But then I can't do my search.  If I type ($(title).search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0), I get a TypeError: $(...).search is not a function.

Comment: $(title).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0)  if title was an element of HTML yes.  But now that title is a string from a property, I thought that  $(title).search(..) would work.

Answer (score 0):

When looping through an array of objects, as you're doing, each time you loop, you get the next instance of your object.

So, in your example, `book` is a simple object, within your forEach loop. So the statement `book[index]` is wrong.

The way to access your title property would be:

```
book.Title
```

Continuing with your code, replace `$(title).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i"))` with the following line:

```
book.Title.search(new RegExp(filter, "i))
```

`book.Title` is a string and you can apply the javascript `search` method to a string. When you write `$(title)`, jQuery is trying to find an element in the DOM based on the book's title. I don't think that is what you're trying to do.